# Trying to uninstall a program using wmic doesn't actually uninstall

Tags: windows, batch-file, wmic

so I want to make a batch script to uninstall a program that is present both in Control Panel and the Settings menu with the same name. However when I run the command `wmic product where name="Mechanic Manager" call uninstall /nointeractive` I get this output:

```
Executing (\\USER\ROOT\CIMV2:Win32_Product.IdentifyingNumber="{905F5A3C-0321-4935-9A64-E96F32D3DC83}",Name="APPNAME",Vendor="MeLul",Version="1.0.0")->Uninstall()
Method execution successful.
Out Parameters:
instance of __PARAMETERS
{
        ReturnValue = 1603;
};
```

Even after this when I go to Control Panel or the Settings menu the program is still there and its files are still in place. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Found out that it happened because I wasn't running the command with enough privileges. Running the batch as admin solved the issue.

Comment: `ERROR_INSTALL_FAILURE

1603 (0x643)

Fatal error during installation.`

Comment: Did you run your batch file elevated, or as a user with the required privileges? If not, I'd advise it. Also, just in case you're not aware, there are no parameters accepted by the uninstall method, so you can safely try it without the `/nointeractive` option.

Comment: @Compo Yup I wasn't running it with enough privileges thank you. Goddamnit that's a bad design saying "Method execution successful" and then there was actuall an error...

Comment: The method worked so no wmic error. But it tells you what happened through a Win32 or COM return value.

Answer (score 0):

I have ran into this issue before. The msiexec.exe service sometimes gets caught up. Try to wmic /node:"computername" process where name="msiexec.exe" delete and then double check it deleted by either running command again or looking yourself by wmic /node:"computername" process list brief  after it is gone try uninstalling agian. With the same code. If that doesnt work clear out again and manually do it by creating a batch script and installer and run batch script. wmic /node:"computername" process call create "C:\folderwithbat\batfile.bat" and do it like that. It should work then. If that doesnt work restart windows installer.